# Error creating bean with name 'fieldServiceImpl' defined in file []: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting this error:

> 2017-02-13 11:53:48.497  WARN 13276 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'fieldServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [...\bin\co\com\service\impl\FieldServiceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'co.com.service.mapper.FieldMapper' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {}
>
> 2017-02-13 11:53:48.679  WARN 13276 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed
>   (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named
>   'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry'
>   available)
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of constructor in co.com.service.impl.FieldServiceImpl
>   required a bean of type 'co.com.service.mapper.FieldMapper' that could
>   not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'co.com.service.mapper.FieldMapper'
>   in your configuration.

I have this classes:
FieldMapper.java

```
package co.com.service.mapper;

import co.com.domain.*;
import co.com.service.dto.FieldDTO;

import org.mapstruct.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Mapper for the entity Field and its DTO FieldDTO.
 */
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface FieldMapper {

    FieldDTO fieldToFieldDTO(Field field);

    List<FieldDTO> fieldsToFieldDTOs(List<Field> fields);

    @Mapping(target = "productionOrderFields", ignore = true)
    Field fieldDTOToField(FieldDTO fieldDTO);

    List<Field> fieldDTOsToFields(List<FieldDTO> fieldDTOs);
}
```

FieldService.java

```
package co.com.service;

import co.com.service.dto.FieldDTO;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Service Interface for managing Field.
 */
public interface FieldService {

    /**
     * Save a field.
     *
     * @param fieldDTO the entity to save
     * @return the persisted entity
     */
    FieldDTO save(FieldDTO fieldDTO);

    /**
     *  Get all the fields.
     *  
     *  @return the list of entities
     */
    List<FieldDTO> findAll();

    /**
     *  Get the "id" field.
     *
     *  @param id the id of the entity
     *  @return the entity
     */
    FieldDTO findOne(Long id);

    /**
     *  Delete the "id" field.
     *
     *  @param id the id of the entity
     */
    void delete(Long id);
}
```

FieldServiceImpl.java

```
package co.com.service.impl;

import co.com.service.FieldService;
import co.com.domain.Field;
import co.com.repository.FieldRepository;
import co.com.service.dto.FieldDTO;
import co.com.service.mapper.FieldMapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Service Implementation for managing Field.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class FieldServiceImpl implements FieldService{

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FieldServiceImpl.class);

    private final FieldRepository fieldRepository;

    private final FieldMapper fieldMapper;

    public FieldServiceImpl(FieldRepository fieldRepository, FieldMapper fieldMapper) {
        this.fieldRepository = fieldRepository;
        this.fieldMapper = fieldMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Save a field.
     *
     * @param fieldDTO the entity to save
     * @return the persisted entity
     */
    @Override
    public FieldDTO save(FieldDTO fieldDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Field : {}", fieldDTO);
        Field field = fieldMapper.fieldDTOToField(fieldDTO);
        field = fieldRepository.save(field);
        FieldDTO result = fieldMapper.fieldToFieldDTO(field);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     *  Get all the fields.
     *  
     *  @return the list of entities
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<FieldDTO> findAll() {
        log.debug("Request to get all Fields");
        List<FieldDTO> result = fieldRepository.findAll().stream()
            .map(fieldMapper::fieldToFieldDTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));

        return result;
    }

    /**
     *  Get one field by id.
     *
     *  @param id the id of the entity
     *  @return the entity
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public FieldDTO findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Field : {}", id);
        Field field = fieldRepository.findOne(id);
        FieldDTO fieldDTO = fieldMapper.fieldToFieldDTO(field);
        return fieldDTO;
    }

    /**
     *  Delete the  field by id.
     *
     *  @param id the id of the entity
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Field : {}", id);
        fieldRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

What should I do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined one 2-argument consturctor in the class, you should autowire the dependencies so that Spring knows what to inject and how to invoke the constructor:

```
@Autowired
public FieldServiceImpl(FieldRepository fieldRepository, FieldMapper fieldMapper) {
        this.fieldRepository = fieldRepository;
        this.fieldMapper = fieldMapper;
}
```

Alternatively put autowired on fields and remove the consturctor whatsoever:

```
@Autowired
private FieldRepository fieldRepository;

@Autowired 
private FieldMapper fieldMapper;
```

**Upate**

Also, i think you need to have an implementation somewhere of the `FieldMapper` interface and it should be marked with @Component or @Service annotation:

```
@Component
public class FieldMapperImpl implements FieldMapper{}
```

As it seems that no implementation is registered in the Spring Cotnext.